# Match all repeated regex patterns in php

Tags: php, regex

Can anybody please help with this reg ex problem?

I want to get all components of this example text:

```
filter:bundesland|4-berlin|6-hamburg|3-nordrhein-westphalen:stadt|3-koeln|2-dresden:typ|5-schule|2-kindergarten|6-hort
```

I am matching this string using:

```
filter(:(bundesland|stadt|typ)(\|\d-[a-z\s-]*)*)*
```

I need to get something like this as a result:

```
Array
(
    ['bundesland'] => Array
        (
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 6
            [3] => 3
        )

    ['stadt'] => Array
        (
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 2
        )

    ['typ'] => Array
        (
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 6
        )

)
```

(I don't care about the labels. Just need the IDs)

Comment: Can you post what exactly you're trying to find? Components doesn't say much.

Comment: Not sure, but maybe this could help? http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ua1-cdu

Comment: @nevermind Your PHP solution comes very close to what I need. I will stick to this if I can't do the same with a single preg_match_all magic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this PHP code:

```
$s = 'filter:bundesland|4-berlin|6-hamburg|3-nordrhein-westphalen:stadt|3-koeln|2-dresden:typ|5-schule|2-kindergarten|6-hort';
$result = array();
preg_replace_callback('~:(\w+)([^:]+)~', function ($m) use (&$result) {
        preg_match_all('/(?<=\|)[0-9]+/', $m[2], $sm); $result[$m[1]] = $sm[0]; }, $s);
print_r($result);
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
    [bundesland] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 6
            [2] => 3
        )
    [stadt] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 2
        )
    [typ] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 6
        )
)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
$pattern = '~(?:(?:filter|\G(?!\A)):(\w+)\||\G(?!\A))(\d+)[^\d:\s]*~';

$result = array();

if (preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
    foreach ($matches as $m) {
        if (!empty($m[1])) $current = $m[1];
        $result[$current][] = $m[2];
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: What if I also want to match ":umkreis|10559-2km" ? It is not working because of the [^\d:\s].

Comment: @user1998613: replace it with: `[^|:\s]*\|?`